# Trying to Understand How Honda Ignition Timing Works

Tags: automotive, timing, inductive

So, I know this isn't an automotive group (per say), but I think that is exactly what I need. In the most simple terms, I've been dissecting my 2001 Honda Accord (3.0 V6 for what it's worth) to understand how the whole ignition/injection system works. Over the past few days, I've been probing around the crank sensor and the TDC (Top Dead Center) sensors to try and understand how the timing is calculated.

The engine has a reluctor wheel behind the crankshaft timing gear, and an inductive pickup, nearby. The confusion started when I looked at the wheel and realized it had 9, equidistant tangs that the pickup sees.

By my understanding, in most cars, you would have a missing tang in this reluctor wheel to help align top dead center of the crankshaft.

So I guess, my question is: How would an inductive pickup be able to determine TDC on this system with these equally spaced teeth? If at all?

It would honestly seem as though Honda is being solely reliant on the TDC/Camshaft sensors. (In fact, the car runs fine without the crank sensor plugged in).

Comment: Is there any difference in the width of a tang? (You've already indicated that they are equally spaced, but I wonder if the tone ring is completely symmetrical in all respects.) Also, is it possible that there's another sensor for determining when a full revolution has taken place?

Comment: @clkinder1 the phrase is `per se`

Comment: i would think that maybe the reluctance wheel requires two turns per cycle ... that would produce 18 pulses, which divides by 6 evenly ... maybe the index pulse is generated by something else

Comment: @jsotola the standard of education these days - latin and greek not in school syllabi anymore I suppose... :)

Comment: Won’t the crank position and cam position align for cyl 1...

Comment: Maybe it just uses the distributor with manual strobe on spark#1 for TDC and phase for something else

Comment: jsotola You know... I honestly know that, I was typing late at night, and it just alluded me for some reason.

TonyStewartEE75 The thing is that there isn't any distributor. It's completely driven from crank and cam sensors (By my understanding of it).

jonk The tangs are all the same width, so I would figure that there has to be something else at play. I don't know of any such sensor, however.

@SolarMike The way the cam reluctor wheel is designed, each pulse signifies another cylinder at TDC. And both cams have representations of different cylinders.

Comment: “Alluded me” or eluded me?

Comment: @SolarMike I need to just get off the internet, right now. I even double checked myself. I'll go back to high school for a few years. I definitely meant eluded. I'll just answer one comment at a time from now on.